# center right-aligned svg element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I am trying to center horizontally custom scroll indicator. I would like to center it in `#slideDown div`. I tried this code, which moves scroll indicator close to center, but not exactly.

```
#slideDown{
display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

}
```

I think the problem arises, because the image I drew is right-aligned as shown here:
[image]

It should be center-aligned like this:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

```
Scroll indicator HTML

    <div id="slideDown">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  display="block" margin="auto" width="22" height="26" viewBox="-1 -1 22 26" class="arrows arrows-1">
          <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#666">
            <path d="M0 0l10 12L20 0" class="a1"></path>
            <path d="M0 12l10 12 10-12" class="a2"></path>
          </g>
        </svg>
    </div>





Scroll indicator CSS:
.arrows {
  padding: 2em;
  -webkit-animation-name: arrowsOpacity;
          animation-name: arrowsOpacity;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3.5s;
          animation-duration: 3.5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
          animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.arrows-1 path {
  -webkit-animation-name: arrows-1-anim;
          animation-name: arrows-1-anim;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
          animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.arrows-1 path.a1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-delay: 0s;

}
.arrows-1 path.a2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
          animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes arrowsOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes arrows-1-anim {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes arrows-1-anim {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


#slideDown{
display: flex;
  justify-content: center;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is as I have pasted the code provided and made a JSfiddle, and it seems to work fine. Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/8cvb8bw1/

Maybe your flexbox is wrapping other elements and breaking the layout? Hard to say if you only provided an excerpt of the code.

```
#slideDown {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If you hover over your scroll indicator with Developer Tools open, you will see that your scroll ind is indeed in the center of the box, while mine is right aligned.

Comment: I added an image.

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? The code you posted works as it should.

Comment: svg wasn't centered in it's container. I increased svg's width and the problem disappeared.